# .htaccess RewriteRule parameters

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a simple .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.+)-([0-9]+)\.html$ book.php?title=$1&id=$2
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.html$ search.php?search=$1
```

If a users enter "**php-for-dumies-10.html**" it going to be served as "**book.php?title=php-for-dummies&id=10**". That works fine.

If a user enters "**phpbook.html**" it going to be served as "**search.php?search=phpbook**". That works fine too.

The problem is if a user enters "**directory/php-for-dumies-10.html**" (adding a directory in the URL) insted of getting "**book.php?title=directory/php-for-dumies&id=10**" as expected,  i'm getting "**search.php?search=book.php/php-for-dumies-10**"

Why does the second RewriteRule execute instead of the first one? Is because i'm adding a slash? And more important, where is the "**book.php**/php-for-dummies-10" parameter is coming from?

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.+)-([0-9]+)\.html$ book.php?title=$1&id=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.html$ search.php?search=$1 [L]
```

Actually, both rewrites are executing. By adding an [L] flag it prevents subsequent rules from executing. This should force only the first rule to execute if its a match.

Comment: Thank you, that's correct! Now I'm just trying to understand why if I don't use the [L] flag and enter (ex. "phpbooks.html" or "php-for-dummies-10.html") just one RewriteRule is executed. And if I add a directory (ex. "/directorio/php-for-dummies-10.html") then both RewriteRules seems to execute. Of course, with the [L] flags this get corrected, I'm just trying to figure it out.